# Ember - How to send data down to a component?

Tags: ember.js, components, ember-router

I'm building an Ember app that needs to fade out a background DIV when a form input becomes focused.

I have defined actions on my Application route, and set a property in my model (because I'm trying to do this without a controller, like the Ember 2.0 way). I'm trying to do Action Up, Data Down. I have the actions going up to the Application route, but the data just isn't making it back down to the component.

I have the actions bubbling up to the application route just fine, but when I update the property `this.controllerFor('application').set('showBackground', true);` it never makes it back down to the component.

I have this fading out background image on every route of my site, so moving all the actions to each route seems like a lot of code duplication.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// Application route.js
var ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            showBackground: false
        });     
    },

    setupController: function(controller, models) {
        controller.setProperties(models);
    },  

    action: {
        showBackground: function(){
            // This runs fine
            this.controllerFor('application').set('showBackground', true);
        },

        hideBackground: function(){
            // This runs fine           
            this.controllerFor('application').set('showBackground', false);     
        }
    }

});

// Background component.js
var BackgroundImage = Ember.Component.extend({

    // This never runs for some reason!?
    controlImage: function(){
        if( this.get('showBackground') ) {
            // Open menu!
            console.log('show image');
        } else {
            // Close menu!
            console.log('hide image');
        }
    }.observes('showBackground')

});

// Login template.hbs
{{background-image showBackground=showBackground}}
```

Is this the correct way to replace "properties" and controllers with routes? All the "move to Ember 2.0" advice I can find doesn't mention how to replace high level properties.

**EDIT**
I created a JSbin, but I'm not sure if it's setup correctly for the 2.0 style (no controllers), as the import/export (ES6?) stuff doesn't work on JSbin.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wunalohona/1/edit?html,js,console,output

I couldn't actually get any of the actions to bubble correctly.

Comment: Have you defined `showBackground` on your `Application` controller? Also, you are passing `showBackground` in your handlebars _(`{{background-image showBackground=showBackground}}`)_, but I'm guessing that is passing the reference to the `action` since that part is working. You may have some naming collisions trying to pass a `showBackground` property _and_ a reference to a `showBackground` action: `{{background-image showBackground=showBackground showBackground=showBackground}}`

Comment: Can you create a failing bin at emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: @blessenm Added JSbin. Thnaks for taking a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Here is the working demo.**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jukaco/1/edit?js,output)

There were multiple issues in the jsbin you provided. Here are some of the issue I fixed.

1. You need to specify the routes, components on the App namespace or Ember will not be able to find it. The resolver used in ember-cli is custom.

   > `var ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({` should be
   >   `App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({`
   >
   > `var BackgroundImage = Ember.Component.extend({` should be
   >   `App.BackgroundImageComponent = Em.Component.extend({`

[**More about it here.**](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/concepts/naming-conventions/)

2. You don't need to specify the `setupController` method in the route. By default the model returned from the model hook is set to the model property of the controller.

   https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.11.1/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L1543
3. The proxying behavior of ObjectController along with ObjectController has been deprecated.

   Now refer model property by adding `model.`+modelPropertyName
   [You can read more about this in the deprecation page for v1.11](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/)
4. `action` in the ApplicationRoute should be `actions`

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, dare I say this should be in the official docs!

Comment: The `model.+modelPropertyName` works great, but should something like this not be stored in the model? This type of setting seems perfect for controller properties, but I could never figure out how to set them on a route?

Comment: This is when you can use setupController. Just need to remember to call super or set the model to the controller. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jukaco/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: What do you think of the `setupController` function mentioned https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97? It seems they recommend setting properties using that and a model. I'm confused about the "right" way to do this.

Comment: Just read through the doc. Yes set the model to a property name on the controller other than 'model' to avoid creating a proxy. The 'setProperties' method along with RSVP hash does that for us. But you can also just use controller.set('showBackground', false); in the setupController hook.